# In python parallel processing, how to find first process calls the function?

Tags: python

I have following code snippet which reads list of CSV files and merge them into a single csv.

```
import multiprocessing

def do():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(max_threads)
    list_of_csvs=[]
    outputdir = 'output/'
    for csvFile in glob(outputdir + '*.csv'):
        list_of_csvs.append(csvFile)
    pool.map(writeToSingleCSV, list_of_csvs)
    pool.close()

def writeToSingleCSV(csvFile):
    with open('singleDataFile.csv', 'a') as singleFile:
        inFile = open(csvFile, 'r')
        for line in inFile:
            singleFile.write(line)
```

Above is code working, but I want to skip the header of following CSV files.(because all csv files contain same header)How can I skip the header from 2nd file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you write the Header separately? Something like this

```
import multiprocessing

def do():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(max_threads)
    list_of_csvs=[]
    outputdir = 'output/'
    for csvFile in glob(outputdir + '*.csv'):
        list_of_csvs.append(csvFile)
    writeToHEADERCSV(list_of_csvs[0])
    pool.map(writeToSingleCSV, list_of_csvs)
    pool.close()

def writeToHEADERCSV(csvFile):
    with open('singleDataFile.csv', 'a') as singleFile:
        inFile = open(csvFile, 'r')
        # Get the first line and write it on the file 

def writeToSingleCSV(csvFile):
    with open('singleDataFile.csv', 'a') as singleFile:
        inFile = open(csvFile, 'r')
        for line in inFile:
            # skip the first line which is header
```

Comment: Nice Approach  :)

Answer (score 2):

Another Approach: using Pandas can be helpful  where `ignore_index=True` can resolve header issue

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob("*.xlsx"): #read all xlsx file from a folder
    df = pd.read_excel(f)
    all_data = all_data.append(df,ignore_index=True)
print (all_data.describe())
all_data.to_excel('SingleFile.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just append the header prior to executing the mapping to writeToSingleCSV and make writeToSingleCSV ignore the headers by default.

```
import multiprocessing

def do():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(max_threads)
    list_of_csvs=[]
    outputdir = 'output/'
    for csvFile in glob(outputdir + '*.csv'):
        list_of_csvs.append(csvFile)
     #Write a CSV file with the header
     csv_with_header = list_of_csvs.pop()
     writeToSingleCSV(csv_with_header, ignoreHeader=False)
     #Write the following CSV files without the header
     pool.map(writeToSingleCSV, list_of_csvs)
     pool.close()

def writeToSingleCSV(csvFile, ignoreHeader=True):
    with open('singleDataFile.csv', 'a') as singleFile:
        inFile = open(csvFile, 'r')
        if ignoreHeader:
            #Ignore/Remove header from inFile - I would ignore len(header) characters
        for line in inFile:
            singleFile.write(line)
```

This keeps it simple, explicit and should be easy to implement.